# SQLite3, failing db->query

Tags: php, database, sqlite

Ii'm trying to build a webform which will work with a database(SQLite3). I'm using PHP. So far I have a file in which I create the database and it's table(mojaDB.php), a file with html form(myForm.html) and a file with insert and display(mojaDBINsert.php). The two first seem to work correctly, but when I run the third file I'm getting 'query failed' message and I don't know why or how can I check it? I would also like to know how can I check whether the db and tables were created?

I'd be very grateful should somebody hel me with the following issues:
* not showing inserted values, showing die('failed') instead
* is the db and table created at all?

code with insert and show(mojaDBINsert.php):

```
 <?php
    //open the database
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:mydb.db');

    $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];

    //inserts row
    $db->exec("INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES ('".$firstname."')");
    echo "Inserted row into table users <br />";

    //drop
 //   $db->exec('DROP TABLE users');
    $tablesquery = $db->query("SELECT sql FROM users") or die('query failed');
    echo $tablesquery;
    $table = $tablesquery -> fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC);
    echo '<pre>'.$table['sql'].'</pre>';
    $db->close();
    ?>
```

creating db and table

```
<?php

    //opens db
    #$db = new SQLite3('sqlite:mydb.db');
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:mydb.db');

    //creates a user table
    $db->exec('CREATE TABLE users (name varchar(255))');
    echo "Table users has been created <br />";

    //inserts row
    $db->exec('INSERT INTO users(name) VALUES ("anna")');
    echo "Inserted row into table users <br />";



 //drop
  //  $db->exec('DROP TABLE users');
    ?>
```

form

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="mojaDBINsert.php" class="form-horizontal" method="post" name="register_form" role="form">
    <h2>Registration Form</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col" for="firstname">First Name</label>
        <div class="col">
            <input class="form-control" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" type="text">
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col">
                <button type="submit">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<script>
function myAjax() {
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'script.php',
           data:{action:'call_this'},
           success:function(html) {
             alert(html);
           }

      });
 }
</script>

<a href="" onclick="myAjax()" class="deletebtn">Delete</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you're using PDO, you should use prepared queries instead of concatenating variables.

Comment: If you drop the table you want to insert into, then why are you surprised that the insertion failed?

Comment: Maybe you don't understand what `DROP TABLE users` does?

Comment: I've commented out the drop line and restarted the whole db but unfortunately I'm still getting die('query failed'). @Barmar

Comment: Change it to `die($db->errorInfo()[2])` so you see the error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
SELECT sql FROM users
```

to

```
SELECT name FROM users
```

since there's no `sql` column in your `users` table.

You also have several problems in your PHP. It should be:

```
$tablesquery = $db->query("SELECT name FROM users") or die($db->errorInfo()[2]);
// echo $tablesquery; // can't echo an object
while ($row = $tablesquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<pre>'.$row['name'].'</pre><br>';
}
$db->close();
```

Comment: it worked I no longer have query die('sth') but it's not printing what I'm inserting as well. I only got 'Inserted row into table users'. Any ideas?

Comment: It's `$tablesquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ARRAY)`. And to show the name it's `$table['name']`. And you need to do it in a loop to get every name. And you can't do `echo $tablesquery;` because it's an object, not a string. Maybe it's time for you to take a step back and learn SQL and PDO?